# What is the difference between ado.net data services and WCF data services?

Tags: wcf, ado.net, wcf-data-services

I understand it's the same thing.

Do you concur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same thing. [WCF Data Services were previously known as ADO .NET Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106).